# Check If File Exists Before downloading the file

Tags: android, file, android-download-manager

I am using download manager to download the file. The code for downloading the file is as follow.

```
   private String DownloadData(Uri uri, View v, String textview) {

    long downloadReference;

    // Create request for android download manager
    dm = (DownloadManager)getContext().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    //Setting title of request
    request.setTitle(textview);

    //Setting description of request
    request.setDescription("Android Data download using DownloadManager.");

    //Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getContext(), DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, File.separator + "Dr_Israr_Ahmad" + File.separator + textview+".mp3");

    //Enqueue download and save into referenceId
    downloadReference = dm.enqueue(request);

    return null
}
```

The above code works fine. What i need to do now is if the file is already downloaded than i want my app to play it. The code which is used is

```
   String path = String.valueOf(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+ File.separator+"Dr_Israr_Ahmad" + File.separator +filename+".mp3"));

                File file = new File(path);

                if(file.exists()){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),path+ "/n exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (!file.exists()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Downloading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.digitalsguide.com/mobile-apps/dr-israr-ahmad/audios/"+filename+".mp3");
                   String filepath = DownloadData(uri,view,filename);
                }
```

but the problem is the condition is true even if the file doesn't exist. Is there a problem in my path ? kindly help me out,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I  detected some strange behavior with `exists` time ago and changed it to `isFile`:

```
File file = new File(path);
if (file.isFile()) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), path + "/n exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Downloading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // ...
}
```

I think the mobile, somehow, created a directory every time `new File()` was executed.
Check this.

Comment: this solution is to check if the file exist locally but what if you need to check if the file exist remotely?

Comment: @leeCoder - Then you ask a new question, or search for an existing one that answers it. Because that isn't what >this< question is about ...

Answer (score 1):

Because `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` returns `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<PACKAGE_ID>/files/Download`. It's not the  folder where `DownloadManager` downloads files when we set `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your path like the example shown below:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+ "/" +filename);
```

Here filename is example.pdf
you can then check if file exists or not

Answer (score -1):

`.getExternalFilesDir(yourFilePath)` creates a directory in your code. so use it like this.

```
String path = String.valueOf(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+ File.separator+"Dr_Israr_Ahmad" + File.separator +filename+".mp3");
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked.